Edit MS Word fields formula but preserve Number Format
I need to change the formula in a field of a MS Word document.

This is the current Formula and Format:

I simply do this with:
Sub changeFormula()
    ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Code.Text = "=Test1+Test2+Test3"
End Sub

The result looks like this:

My problem is, that the Format is gone and I can't figure out how it can be recreated or preserved.

If you display the field code in the document you will see that the number format is part of .Code.Text You need to modify your macro to only change the first part of the text instead of all of it.

genius. thank you very much!
